# How to make an alert when an animation reaches a certain point on the screen. Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an animation and it runs across the screen continuously. Now I'm trying to get an alert when you touch the animation in a certain part of the screen.

Currently I have got to the point where if you touch the middle of the screen you get an alert.

**SelectedCellViewController.h**

```
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface SelectedCellViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIImageView *rocket;
}

@end
```

**SelectedCellViewController.m**

```
#import "SelectedCellViewController.h"

@interface SelectedCellViewController ()

@end

@implementation SelectedCellViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

[self performSelector:@selector(imageSpawn:) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

  }


     - (void) imageSpawn:(id) sender
   {

      UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ae"];
      rocket = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
       rocket.frame = CGRectMake(-25, 200, 25, 40);
       [UIView animateWithDuration:5
                      delay:0.2f
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^(){rocket.frame=CGRectMake(345, 200, 25, 40);}
                 completion:^(BOOL fin) {
                 }];

   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ballTapped:)];
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:rocket];

}

-(void)ballTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{

//  [rocket.layer removeAllAnimations];
NSLog(@"Tag = %d", gesture.view.tag);

 CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
```

rocket.frame = CGRectMake(location.x,location.y,25,40);

```
 CGPoint location1 = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
CGRect rectToCompare =  CGRectMake(10.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f, 42.0f);

if (CGRectContainsPoint(rectToCompare, location1)) {

    //trigger an event.
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tapped row!"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Shot"]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes, I did!"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

To get values for view attributes in the middle of the animation, you have to use the view layer's `presentationLayer`. As the [documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> The layer object returned by this method provides a close approximation of the layer that is currently being displayed onscreen. While an animation is in progress, you can retrieve this object and use it to get the current values for those animations.

Therefore, you can use `view.layer.presentationLayer.frame` where `view` is your `UIImageView` to get the current location of the animation layer on screen. Using this, it is trivial to test whether the frame is within the boundaries that you want to detect.